# Using SecureZeroMemory in Delphi

Tags: c++, c, security, delphi, memory

I understand there is a `SecureZeroMemory` function in C.
The function implementation is defined in `<WinnNT.h>` as `RtlSecureZeroMemory` function.

QNS: How can `SecureZeroMemory` be used in Delphi? Did Delphi release a library that contains that function? I'm using Delphi 7. `Windows.pas` only has `ZeroMemory` but not `SecureZeroMemory`.

Comment: I do not have a Delphi compiler and RTL here right now, but if I recall correctly, the `ZeroMemory` of Windows.pas is actually *not* a function of the Windows API, but rather a wrapper for the Delphi's `FillChar` function.

Comment: Yes that's right. That function is just a wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, the only difference between `ZeroMemory` and `SecureZeroMemory` is `SecureZeroMemory` is implemented as an inline function, ensuring it won't be optimised out by the compiler.

I don't think Delphi performs the same level of compiler optimisation, so `ZeroMemory` calls shouldn't be optimised out.

Comment: I think you got the logic inverted. `ZeroMemory` is inline, and can be optimized out. `SecureZeroMemory` is essentially a Win32 function in a DLL, and the call cannot be optimized out at compile time.

Comment: @MSalters May I know which Win32 DLL is SecureZeroMemory found in?

Comment: SecureZeroMemory is not an exposed function in any Win32 DLL. @glob is right that SecureZeroMemory is inline, as stated in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Since according to MSDN, [SecureZeroMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28VS.85%29.aspx) is actually defined as the `RtlSecureZeroMemory()`, you can declare `SecureZeroMemory()` as follows:

```
  procedure SecureZeroMemory(_ptr: Pointer; cnt: Longint); external 'kernel32.dll' name 'RtlSecureZeroMemory';
```

`SecureZeroMemory()` is merely an alias of `RtlSecureZeroMemory()`.

Comment: I didn't know that `[Rtl]SecureZeroMemory` was an exported DLL function. But I suppose you have tried your code, and hence, that it *is*. Still, per my answer, I do not think there is ever any *need* to use this function rather than `ZeroMemory` (`FillChar` with #0) in Delphi.

Comment: Can't find RtlSecureZeroMemory,SecureZeroMemory, RtlZeroMemory, or ZeroMemory anywhere in kernel32.dll. Those functions are not exported in any Win32 DLL.

Comment: @seveleven, I've just checked `kernel32.dll` using a dll export viewer tool, and indeed RtlSecureZeroMemory() exists in `kernel32.dll`.

Comment: However, I didn't test yet whether the MSDN statement applies in Delphi, "If ZeroMemory were called in this example instead of SecureZeroMemory, the compiler could optimize the call because the szPassword buffer is not read from before it goes out of scope ..." I know, `ZeroMemory()` was implemented as `FillChar` with `0` in Delphi, but the case in the MSDN example should be empirically tested to ensure that doesn't apply in Delphi programs.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Delphi compiler available right now, but I do not think there is a need for `SecureZeroMemory`.

I do remember that in Delphi, the Win32 API functions/macros `CopyMemory` and `MoveMemory` are **identical** (they are both implemented just as the pointer "versions" of the `Move` RTL function). Hence, the remark at [the MSDN `CopyMemory` reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366535(VS.85).aspx) saying that you must use `MoveMemory` rather than `CopyMemory` is the blocks overlap, is irrelevant. Delphi's `Move` *always* makes the right thing.

I **think** the same thing applies to `ZeroMemory` and `SecureZeroMemory`. The first is implemented as `FillChar` with #0, and if there would be a `SecureZeroMemory` function for Deplhi, I think it would also just be a `FillChar` with #0. (If `FillChar` would be ignored at some times, it really should be documented in the Delphi reference, but it isn't.)

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at the MSDN help here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The only question whether Delphi's compiler removes ZeroMemory as an optimization result,
athough i doubt that.