# How can I quickly clear a record of simple types?

Tags: delphi

I have a structure defined like this:

```
const
  MaxSignalRecords=255;
type
  TSignalRecord=record
   signal1  : integer;
   signal2  : integer;
   signal3  : integer;
   signal4  : integer;
   signal5  : integer;
   signal6  : integer;
   bsignal1 : Boolean;
   bsignal2 : Boolean;
   bsignal3 : Boolean;
   bsignal4 : Boolean;
   bsignal5 : Boolean;
   bsignal6 : Boolean;
  end;

TListSignals = Array[0..MaxSignalRecords-1] of TSignalRecord;
```

This structure is used to  make thousands of calculations in an algorithm like this:

```
for i:=1 to 900000 do
begin
  CleartheList(MyList);
  DotheMath(MyList);
  DotheChart(MyList);
end;
```

I am looking for a fast way to initializate the values of my `TListSignals` to 0 and `false`.

Now I am using this :

```
procedure ClearListSignals(var ListSignals:TListSignals);
var
  i :Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to MaxSignalRecords - 1 do
  with ListSignals[i] do
  begin
   signal1   :=0;
   signal2   :=0;
   signal3   :=0;
   signal4   :=0;
   signal5   :=0;
   signal6   :=0;
   bsignal1  :=false;
   bsignal2  :=false;
   bsignal3  :=false;
   bsignal4  :=false;
   bsignal5  :=false;
   bsignal6  :=false;
  end;
end;
```

How can I improve the performance of the `ClearListSignals` procedure?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065821/how-to-properly-free-records-that-contain-various-types-in-delphi-at-once#11066205

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763864/how-to-set-default-value-to-record-in-delphi

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176198/difference-between-initialize-default-and-fillchar

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can use the `ZeroMemory` procedure located in the `Windows` unit.

```
var
  MyList : TListSignals;
begin
     ZeroMemory(@Mylist,SizeOf(MyList));
end;
```

Comment: So if I was to read the value of any ListSignals[i].signal1 this would equal 0? Nice way to avoid the initial assignments.

Comment: @Altar the question and answer is only for a record of simple types.

Comment: i suppose answer from ZENsan is more correct. need to use `Default` and no hack with direct memory access

Comment: @SolarWind, if the record contains strings have values, ZeroMemory will cause a memory leak. You can call Finalize() on the record first to deallocate the strings before calling ZeroMemory.

Comment: @dan-gph-Salvador shows no strings in his record so zeromemory works in this case.

Comment: It would be nice if your answer will mention the "ugly" face of ZeroMemory :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176198/difference-between-initialize-default-and-fillchar

Answer (score 30):

You should use the standard Delphi language function Default()!

```
const
  MaxSignalRecords = 255;

type
  TSignalRecord = record
    ...
    bsignal6 : Boolean;
  end;

var
  X: TSignalRecord
...
X := Default(TSignalRecord);
...
```

And no hack.. as suggested before..

Comment: `Default()` was [introduced in Delphi 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460108/2306907).

Comment: That seems to be the most elegant way. I think that if you have a constructor for a record it should zero the memory for you anyway, so that records work more like classes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176198/difference-between-initialize-default-and-fillchar

Answer (score 16):

```
FillChar(ListSignals, SizeOf(ListSignals), 0);
```

Comment: ZeroMemory is just a wrapper around FillChar(,,0).

Comment: ZeroMemory is an inline that uses FullChar, but ZeroMemory reads a lot better

Comment: FillChar is defined in `System` which makes it platform independant, ZeroMemory only works on Windows.

Comment: FillChar works also with Laazarus and Free Pascal and on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what was said about `FillChar` and `ZeroMemory` (which internally just calls FillChar anyway), you can reduce the size of your record by using `bsignal: set of 1..6;` instead of individual booleans which should speed up the clearing slightly.

Comment: +1 since it's a good idea. booleans will be aligned on 4 or 8 bytes boundaries, so it's like an awful waste of space, therefore speed in this case.

Comment: Really, @A.Bouchez? I thought Booleans were aligned on 1-byte boundaries. Are you saying the total size of the record in the question is 48 instead of 30?

Comment: Booleans will be aligned based on the compiler alignment switch, unless the record is packed. Also, RAM is pretty cheap these days so I would not worry too much about wasted space.

Comment: @Rob: You're right: use sizeof(TSignalRecord) and you'll get... 32, i.e. there will be 1-byte aligned. And the whole record size is then with `packed record`, you'll get sizeof(TSignalRecord)=30. With set of 1..6  you'll have sizeof(TSignalRecord)=28.

Comment: The issue with wasted space is not the monetary cost of RAM but the speed implications that come with poor use of the cache. But it's not so relevant here because Boolean has an alignment of 1.

Comment: Efficient cache use becomes very important now a days. The difference in latency between a L1 cache hit and going to main memory is by now in the same order of magnitude as the difference between main memory and having to go to disk.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SecureZeroMemory

> To avoid undesired effects of
>   optimizing compilers, use the
>   SecureZeroMemory function.
>
> The SecureZeroMemory function fills a
>   block of memory with zeros. It is
>   designed to be a more secure version
>   of ZeroMemory.
>
> Use this function instead of
>   ZeroMemory when you want to ensure
>   that your data will be overwritten
>   promptly, as the compiler can optimize
>   a call to ZeroMemory by removing it
>   entirely.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

LE: here you have how to use it in Delphi if your version does not contain it:

[Using SecureZeroMemory in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030945/using-securezeromemory-in-delphi)

Comment: `SecureZeroMemory` as its name implies, is a security feature. It's not intended for general purpose use. Optimising compilers only remove the call to ZeroMemory if it detects that the memory is not reused later - implying there's no point in clearing it. However, it's possible that the memory could contain a password, but is not reused later. Then you still want to ensure the password is cleared from memory lest it appear in memory dumps, or be accessible by a hacking attack. In OP's case, there is absolutely no need to use `SecureZeroMemory`. Though it is useful to be aware of the function.

Comment: the question and answer is only for a record of simple types